# Alamofire.upload multipartFormData

Tags: java, swift, alamofire

**That i want to set several files with name "file", but in fact i have only 1 file.**
I have some problems with uploading files using Alamofire.upload multipartFormData. I need to upload Java several files into one request name.

For example i use:

```
Alamofire.upload(.POST,URLs.publishTopic_url,
                     multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                        for i in 0 ..< files.count {
                            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: files[i], name: "file[]", fileName:  "\(i)\(NSUUID().UUIDString).jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
                        }

                        for (key, value) in parameters {
                            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: value.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name: key)
                        }
        },
                     encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                        // Handle result
                        switch encodingResult {
                        case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                            upload.responseJSON { response in
                                print(response.request)  // original URL request
                                print(response.response) // URL response
                                print(response.data)     // server data
                                print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

                                let result = response.result.value
                                let json = JSON(result!)
                                print(json)
                                if json["code"].string! == "200"{
                                    success(message: json["message"].string!)
                                }else{
                                    failure(message:"上传失败，请稍后重试！")
                                }
                            }

                        case .Failure(let encodingError):
                            print(encodingError)
                        }
        }
    )
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: @meskobalazs beacuse my server is written in Java